# corona network.download() is not working on android

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I have a function which downloads a weather xml feed and displays it now, if it can't get a connection it loads in the last report or a blank one if it's the first time downloading. This part seems to work fine, but when it has a connection it seems to not want to finish downloading it. It works fine on IOS but on Android it just brings up a loading sign.

This is the function

```
function Display:doQuery(zip, web)
  Display:loadXML() -- calls the functions to display previous or blank weather data
  network.download(web .. zip, "GET",
                   networkListener,
                   "weather.xml",
                   system.TemporaryDirectory)
end
```

also I have seen the weather demo and tried it and the same thing seems to happen it seems.

the network listener is

```
function networkListener(event)
    if (event.isError) then
      print("Network error!")
    else
      loadXML()
   end
end
```

so it reloads the the xml if and when it gets them.

Comment: I think we need more code, what is the code in networkListener, what is in web and zip ?

Comment: the web is an address to the website for the weather info, the zip is the location i'll be using to get it
so~ web is http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/ForecastXML/index.xml?query=" zip is ne2+1nr,

Comment: If the weather demo does the same, then you should file a bug with Corona

Comment: yes my thoughts aswell but theres no bug mention anywhere about this

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you must add the following permission to the "build.settings" file.

```
 settings =
   {
   android =
   {
      usesPermissions =
      {
         "android.permission.INTERNET",
      },
    },
  }
```